# sprintf using the same values multiple times

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the same value in different places when using sprintf, but failing.

```
<?php

$score = 50;
$percent = 10;

$str = "Hello: You scored %s (%s%%). Your score is %2$s %%"; //Problem is here %2$s

echo sprintf($str,$score,$percent);
?>
```

I get this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: s in C:\web\apache\htdocs\sprintf.php on line 6 Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in C:\web\apache\htdocs\sprintf.php on line 8`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$str = 'Hello: You scored %s (%s%%). Your score is %2$s %%';
```

Variables are expanded inside double quotes, so `$s` was treated as a variable, not a formatting option.

If you want to use double quotes, you can escape the dollar sign:

```
$str = "Hello: You scored %s (%s%%). Your score is %2\$s %%";
```

Comment: But I need those double quotes. They're there with a purpose.

Comment: Ok. I put a `\` before the `$` and it's fine now.

Comment: You could also use concatenation instead of interpolation to perform variable substitutions in the string.

Comment: You could `sprintf` the values into the string... :o)

Answer (score 2):

A `$` inside of double quoted strings is used for variable interpolation, PHP is looking for the variable `$s` here. Use single quoted strings and number all your arguments while you're at it:

```
'Hello: You scored %1$s (%1$s%%). Your score is %2$s %%'
```

Comment: I need those double quotes. There are variables in there too. Not show here, but in the script.

Comment: Well then you need to escape the `$`s which are meant to be literal `$`s: `"...%1\$s..."`.

Comment: Ah! Yes! I did just that. Thanks