# argument must be greater then 0 - how is this possible when the value is greater then 0

Tags: php

So I am doing the following in PHP:

```
$cost = $this->reportDataStructure['ext_cost'] / $this->reportDataStructure['quantity'];
var_dump($cost); // Outputs: float(220)
$this->reportDataStructure['cost'] = sprintf("%$.2f", $cost);
```

And I keep getting

```
Warning: sprintf(): Argument number must be greater than zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\rms\site\web\module\Report\controller\InventoryReport.controller.php on line 98
```

which pertains to the line:

```
$this->reportDataStructure['cost'] = sprintf("%$.2f", $cost);
```

But as we can see:

```
var_dump($cost); // Outputs: float(220)
```

So whats going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$` is used in `printf` format strings to specify which argument to print with the specifier after it, e.g.

```
sprintf('%2$f %1$d', $var1, $var2);
```

means it will display `$var2` as a float and then `$var1` as an integer.

You have `$` in your format string, but there's no number before it. So the number isn't greater than 0.

If you explain what you're trying to accomplish with that format string, I can update the answer with the correct way to do it.

If you're just trying to put a `$` before the price, it needs to be *before* the `%`, not after it.

```
$this->reportDataStructure['cost'] = sprintf("$%.2f", $cost);
```

Comment: I got lucky. I didn't know about this `sprintf` feature until I read this question this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261277/sprintf-using-the-same-values-multiple-times/20261358#20261358

Comment: also, make sure to get the order of your `%2$s` arguments right - don't accidentally write `%$2s` like I did this morning.